# Optimize MySQL query with LEFT-OUTER-JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, record

I have 2 tables with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `classi` (
  `nome` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `padre` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `prop` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `metodi` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `descrizione` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nome`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nome` (`nome`),
  UNIQUE KEY `padre` (`padre`,`nome`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `prop` (
  `classe` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nome` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tipo` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `valori` text,
  `descrizione` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`classe`,`nome`),
  UNIQUE KEY `speciale` (`classe`,`nome`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nome` (`classe`,`nome`),
 UNIQUE KEY `tipo` (`classe`,`tipo`,`nome`)
)
```

Here are the rules for my query:

1. "classi" is the MAIN table, "prop" is CHILD table of "classi" (1 to
   N relationship on classi.nome -> prop.classe)
2. I need ALL the records in "classi" and ONLY FIRST "JOINABLE" 
   RECORD of "prop" (where prop.tipo = 'A', order by prop.tipo)
3. The final recordset need to be ordered by classi.nome

This is the query I wrote (and it works):

```
SELECT c.nome, c.prop, c.metodi, p.nome AS pnome, p.tipo
FROM classi c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT nome, classe, tipo FROM prop ORDER BY tipo) p
 ON c.nome = p.classe
WHERE p.tipo = 'A'
GROUP BY c.nome
ORDER BY c.nome;
```

So my final question is: **is it possible to further optimize this query (eg. avoiding derived table or other suggestion) ?**

**Please consider that any solution should be after applied on other db engine (MSSQL, PostgreSQL, ecc.) so I'd need an ANSI and portable solution (or a "translatable" solution).**

Thank you in advance for your reply!

Comment: What is FIRST JOINABLE record of prop? You order by tipo but also filter by it, ordering A's will not give meaningful answer.

Comment: You're right Nikola, try to image that WHERE clause doesn't exists. I have several "tipo" records in prop table for same "classe" (A, B, C,...) but I need ONLY the first one (order by "tipo") for that "classe" (it could be "C" for example becouse for the same "classe" records doesn't exists any "A" or "B" "tipo" record)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
SELECT c.nome, c.prop, c.metodi, p.nome AS pnome, p.tipo
FROM classi c
JOIN prop p
 ON c.nome = p.classe
WHERE p.tipo = 'A'
ORDER BY c.nome;
```

Left join is not working because you have a condition on right table, and there is no need to join to derived table because condition will take care of other prop records.
Also, I don't see how this could work as you have a group by but most of columns are not either grouped or aggregated.

Comment: A nice rewrite of the original query, but it does not cover `ONLY FIRST "JOINABLE" RECORD of "prop"`

Comment: Facepalm :-) missed that part.

Comment: No, original query orders by tipo and then filters 'A's only. There is no provision to ensure only one record is returned for 'A'.

Comment: I know that. I think this is the main reason of the question =)

Comment: If it is then it is very lightly implied. If you read bold text at the end, OP is interested in optimizing the query he posted.

Comment: This might explain the `GROUP BY` presence in the original query. If it does work for the OP, though, the `prop` table is subject to better normalization. UPD: this can't work since (`nome`, `classe`) is the PK.

Comment: I agree with you that this was probably his intention, but his data has "properties" of one "type" only, otherwise he would see duplicates in results and post a different question.

Comment: @newtover: yes, you're right...I'm just trying to understand if the query can be optimized. The one I posted works fine regarding to final goal. But these 2 tables are very huge in production environment and I would like to find a better way (more performance) to get the same result. And I also CAN'T NORMALIZE the tables because they're part of an external software I don't manage.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you simply do the following:

```
SELECT c.nome, c.prop, c.metodi, p.nome AS pnome, p.tipo
FROM classi c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 prop p
 ON c.nome = p.classe
WHERE p.tipo = 'A'
GROUP BY c.nome
ORDER BY c.nome;
```

Comment: No Vikram...yes, in this way query would retrieve the same number of rows...BUT you can't be sure the prop record joined actually is the FIRST ORDER BY tipo column.